# Deploy to Kubernetes in Google Cloud: Challenge Lab

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiyWg.png)

hello i cant solve the task 6 idid all the steps but the problem is till can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0):

It is a **known** bug, i have already raised the ticket with **Qwiklab** support.

However, you can do the workaround like, **BUILD_NUMBER** is `1,2,3,4` based on jenkin job

You build image format should be like : **gcr.io/${PROJECT}/valkyrie-app:dev.${IMAGE_TAG}**

Go to project folder in **GCloud CLI** where **Dockerfile** is run this command

```
gcloud builds submit -t gcr.io/qwiklabs-gcp-00-<Number>/valkyrie-app:dev.5 .
```

Jenkin stage i used to print the build number and **Image tag**

```
stage('Print data') {
      steps {
        script {
          sh "${IMAGE_TAG}"
          sh "${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
        }
      }
    }
```

You can run this command to the application folder. it will submit the build to Google cloud build.

Once the image is pushed to the GCR you can update the image to deployment.yaml file and re-apply it simply.

Once POD are rollbacked, you can wait for 1-2 min and check the status.